# How can I get text value from element

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium

I've got issue with get text element

```
<style id="main-style-inline-css" type="text/css">
body{--accent:141, 65, 48;--accent--tone:199, 111, 92; ...
</style>
```

Tried, but return empty value:

```
theme_Colors = "//style[@id='main-style-inline-css']"
test = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, theme_Colors).text
```

Comment: Shouldn't `id` be `main-style-inline-css` above?

Comment: Yup, it was missclick

Answer (score 0):

```
     driver.find_element(By.XPATH, theme_Colors).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Try innerHTML instead of text as the content there is not text nodes

Answer (score 0):

for python the function is `get_attribute()` then use attribute of `innerHTML` or `innerText`

```
test = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, theme_Colors).get_attribute('innerText')
```